# PHP DateTime __construct() Failed to parse time string (xxxxxxxx) at position x

Tags: php, datetime

I had this construction error when trying to creating a new DateTime object using a timestamp:

> Exception: DateTime::_*construct(): Failed to parse time string (1372622987) at position 8 (8): Unexpected character in DateTime->*_construct()

The object creation code is:

```
$start_date = new DateTime( "@{$dbResult->db_timestamp}" );
```

Where $dbResult->db_timestamp is a valid unix timestamp taken from a database. The timestamp in question was:

> 1372622987

I would understand this error for invalid formats being passed, but this is a genuine timestamp.

The reason this is very strange: I since ran a script to create a new DateTime object with the timestamp passed in as a hard coded value, and it reported no errors.

This seems to have been a one off, but I need an explanation if there is one, as I can't afford for this to happen again.

Comment: Your code seems to work: http://codepad.org/3RxtyU4b

Comment: The error you have posted and the code you have posted do not match.  The error indicates that the timestamp being passed to the `DateTime` constructor doesn't have a leading `@` on it, while the code you posted shows that it is included.  One of those things is inaccurate.

Comment: @SeanBright I can confirm that removing the leading `@` produces this exact error: http://codepad.org/ZPZmXi2x

Comment: This is very interesting. I can assure that the @ has always been in the code, and as I said, it works at all times except this occurrence. I wonder if it wasn't interpreted as a one off. Do we know of any problems of using {} notation instead of joining them with '.' notation?

Comment: I bet that your database result was null.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You should use setTimestamp instead, if you hardcode it:

```
$start_date = new DateTime();
$start_date->setTimestamp(1372622987);
```

in your case

```
$start_date = new DateTime();
$start_date->setTimestamp($dbResult->db_timestamp);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. The strange thing is my code has worked before and since, it was just a random occurrence..

Comment: I always try to use the proper methods instead of magic strings. I know that the @ and U can work if properly used, but they require additional parsing by the php processor and if there is a method to set the timestamp, using an integer, then you gain a few microseconds in the process.

Comment: This is too procedural. This answer is not object orientated. OOP uses constructors. There is a constructor available, so use it. Abani Meher's answer is better, I think.

Comment: I would agree with you if the `DateTime` was immutable and if there was a constructor that accepted a timestamp. For me, a solution that clearly defines an interface `setTimestamp(int)` is preferable to a solution that does accept a magic string, not to mention the performance issues involved.

Answer (score 18):

Use the `createFromFormat` method:

`$start_date = DateTime::createFromFormat("U", $dbResult->db_timestamp);`

**UPDATE**

I now recommend the use of [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Comment: Thanks for one-line solution.

Comment: No worries, be sure to check `$start_date` for validity before using.

Comment: .. that is: `$start_date === false` (rather than `null`), since `createFromFormat` (from what I know) never throws exceptions when failing.

Answer (score 15):

change your code to this

```
$start_date = new DateTime( "@" . $dbResult->db_timestamp );
```

and it will work fine

Comment: That's effectively the same thing isn't it?

Comment: @crush - looks same but you can try and see the difference

Comment: The @ symbol makes all the diference. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php and see the "Unix Timestamp" entry

Comment: The code has worked as it is, it just failed this once - so hard to pin it down to this

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
   /**
     * return date in specific format, given a timestamp.
     *
     * @param  timestamp  $datetime
     * @return string
     */
    public static function showDateString($timestamp)
    {
      if ($timestamp !== NULL) {
        $date = new DateTime();
        $date->setTimestamp(intval($timestamp));
        return $date->format("d-m-Y");
      }
      return '';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$start_date = new DateTime();
$start_date->setTimestamp($dbResult->db_timestamp);
```