# PHP DateTime unable to parse time string from epoch timestamp

Tags: php

I am trying to display the number in hours since a date like this...

```
$timestamp1 = '1517158402';
$timestamp2 = '1530204802';
$timestamp3 = '1548694384';

if ($timestamp1 && $timestamp2 && $timestamp3 ) {

    /* Calculate time */
    $timestamp1_obj = new DateTime($timestamp1);
    $timestamp2_obj = new DateTime($timestamp2);
    $timestamp3_obj = new DateTime($timestamp3);

    $since_start = $timestamp2_obj->diff($timestamp3_obj);
    echo $since_start->h.' hours';

}
```

This is giving me the error message...

```
Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string
```

Anyone any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: See ['DateTime::setTimestamp ( int $unixtimestamp )'](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php)

Comment: `DateTime::__construct()` expects a string with one of the [formats listed here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)

Comment: You can also use `new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp1));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP DateTime \_\_construct() Failed to parse time string (xxxxxxxx) at position x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427503/php-datetime-construct-failed-to-parse-time-string-xxxxxxxx-at-position-x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`setTimestamp`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php).

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp(1171502725);
```

Comment: Thank you, setTimestamp was exactly what was missing!