# DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (May 5 2022 12:00:00:AM) at position 20 (:): Unexpected character

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'm having the following error

```
ErrorException in /*/web/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php line 555:
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (May 5 2022 12:00:00:AM) at position 20 (:): Unexpected character
```

In my list file,

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($r->AttendanceDate)->format('d/m/Y') }}
```

The date in sql is a date time "`2020-05-20 08:13:00.000`"

I've tried some changes like format from DateTime to format to day, I've tried also to parse string and nothing worked.. I've seen some post with the same error but nothing result. Please help me

Comment: look at the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427503/php-datetime-construct-failed-to-parse-time-string-xxxxxxxx-at-position-x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Failed to parse time string (May 5 2022 12:00:00:AM)" is very clear. It can't parse that format. You can tell Carbon what format to expect using the [Carbon::createFromFormat](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation) method.

```php
Carbon::createFromFormat('M j Y h:i:s:A', 'May 5 2022 12:00:00:AM');
```

Format definitions are from PHP's [DateTime::createFromFormat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. I've search a lot and cant found the format to include :s:A !!

Comment: Glad to help. Note if this is coming from a model attribute then you should set up Laravel to do the conversion to a Carbon date automatically. See https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting

Comment: The main reason for this is because i get null from datbase in one field of that row and cant parse.. in that case i need to parse null to anything